# Changing keybindings for Ubuntu using xmodmap fails

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I've changed some of the keybindings for my keyboard using *xmodmap*, I've specifically changed my caps-lock key to point to `CTRL_L` and my `CTRL_L` key to point to `Super_L`.

This registers in *xev* but my caps-lock key still acts like the caps-lock key (aka, pressing the physical caps-lock keys makes everything GO LIKE THIS) during regular use, same with the control key acting like a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and not the <kbd>Super</kbd> key!

I'm using the Swedish keyboard layout.

My scavenging has led me to believe that *xmodmaps* configuration is overridden by *XKB*, I will continue my search.

Any idea what I can do to make my changes work?

Comment: Okay, it all works now:

You need to remember to rebind the modifier keys so for example control is associated with Control_L and Caps_Lock IS NOT associated with any other mod key than mod4!!

Comment: What does your final script look like? I have the same problem. Everything works if I run xmodmap <file> manually, but if Ubuntu runs it as the .Xmodmap then Caps_Lock still produces CAPS

Answer (score 1):

You also need to remove caps lock functionality from the caps lock key using `remove Lock = Caps_Lock` in addition to remapping it.

Comment: Okay, both of my bindings now work under Ubuntu Unity, now I've just gotta make it work for Awesome WM...